# Invisible table based on drop-down list value

Tags: excel, excel-2016

There is a drop-down list with numbers that was made using Data-> Data validation. The goal is to make visible only the number of rows of the table that was chosen from drop-down list without using vba (to make it more easily to edit by ordinary users). The first column of the table contains numbers corresponding to the numbers from the drop-down list. The table also contains the columns with formulas. I choosed to use conditional formating with idea that all the cells of the table will be calculated and then hide those rows of the table that are under the row corresponding to the value of cell with drop-down list. In other words it needs to dynamically change the visible rows of the table or to dynamically form the table (but there is a columns with formulas and I don't know if you can do that without using vba). I've tried different ways but this problem seems difficult for me. Maybe instead of ordinary table you need to use smart-table or power pivot but I don't have experience of using it. Thank You for Your help!

Comment: you cant hide rows/columns automatically without vba... however, you could change the format so it shows simply nothing... if thats still ok with what you are looking for. bu consider: having such a cell as source for your dropdown-list will also show nothing inside it (it still will work, but you cant see what you are selecting)

Comment: @Dirk Reichel the drop-down list values are not based on this table, there is the column in the table with the same numbers, so the drop-down list is always visible. As I said in the post I've chosen conditional formating but I don't know what kind of the rule I need to write. I know how to make the hole table invisible but I need only the part of it to be invisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... let's asume you have the value in `A1`.

Now for the range of `B2:G20`.
Conditional formatting formula: `=ROW()>$A$1`

In the range of `B2:G20` every cell will be formated with a row higher than the value in `A1`

If the format is something like `; ; ;` it looks empty.

Using this example and having 11 in `A1` -> `B12:G20` will be hidden.

However: to set `Row.Hdden = true` you need to do it manually or use VBA :/

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it later as I'm writing from cell phone and Office mobile has limited functions